# CSS/HTML: Input fields not using CSS styles

Tags: html, css, input, styles

I want to style the text input areas on my form, however when I create a style for input in css, it does not actually style the input box.  I have been able to style my button, just not input boxes.

```
<div class="loginContainer">
        <form action ="" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="username" class="label">Username</label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="150">
                        <input type="text" name="username" size="25" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                    </td>
                    <td width="150"> 
                        <input type="password" name="password" size="25" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="remember">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Keep me signed in
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Log in">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

And here is the CSS for it:

```
input[type="text"] {
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    display: block;
}
```

This ends up creating a form which creates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IgJA.png

Note the lack of style on the input fields.  How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of strange that the border radius is not applied, you can try the following ( note the lack of quotes ):

```
input[type=text] {
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    display: block;

    /* new stuff */
    border: 1px solid pink;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: This yields the same result as the image above.  No orange background or pink border.

Comment: I don't see why Petar's answer wouldn't change the results. If this hasn't changed anything on the front-end, try adding "display:none;". If the inputs aren't hidden, you must have either a faulty selector, another selector overruling this one, or the CSS is not being applied for some other reason - and you'll know the problem isn't because inputs are tricky to style.

Comment: Displa:none did not change the results.  Here is the whole CSS file: http://pastebin.com/2CwcNknf

The entire login file is already posted above.

Comment: It is most certainly something in your environment here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zxaA5/ Try doing a fiddle yourself and see if that works for you. If it does then you can compare it to the old one and figure out what's wrong

Comment: The same code that works in jsfiddle does not work in my code and I cannot figure out what is wrong for the life of me.  I got the password field styled, just not the text field now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the for the password field also to be styled you need to add that tag in the style as well, like this:

```
  input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    display: block;
}
```